# How to write hh:mm:ss.fff with Excel::Writer::XLSX in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm generating a report with [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) in Perl. The report already gets generated but unfortunately the format is not correct with extra apostrophes `'`.

- The array fetched from mysql : `$month[$i][7]` (notice: The column is using `time(3)` type. Example: `00:22:12.212`).
- The Perl command used to write the data to excel: `$sheet1->write($row,7,$month[$i][7],$format1);#7`
- The format of column:

  ```
  my $format1 = $workbook->add_format(
  center_across => 1,
  bold => 0,
  size => 11,
  border => 1,
  text_wrap => 1,
  color => 'black',
  bg_color => '#ffffff',
  num_format => 'hh:mm:ss.000',
  align => 'center',
  valign => 'vcenter');
  ```

The apostrophes just show when I double click to column:

> [image: The apostrophes just show when I double click to column]

I have used that data to draw the chart but the column is formatting with text so I think that is why the chart did not show the lines. Should I convert the array to time in Perl before write it to Excel?

---

I'm sorry because the previous question was not clear and my english is not good also.

Thanks you all for support.

Comment: An example code of what you tried would be necessary to know how we can help you. I'd suggest using a regular expression.

Comment: Hi David, 

I have edited my question. Kindly help to solve my issue.

Comment: @RafaelNguyen If you answer to people in comments, you need to add an `@` character in front of their name, like I just did. That way, the person gets a notification. It will also give you auto-complete of the names to make it easier. The owner of the post you are commenting on will always get notified. So if you write to me, you do `@simbabque`. But you can only highlight one person per message. In terms of being friendly, there is no need around here to say _Hi_ or _Thank you_ or _Best regards_ or anything. Your name is under your post, and voting is like saying thanks.

Comment: @simbabque This is noted for the next post.

Comment: You will need to convert the MySQL time to an number that represents the date in Excel. See the [Dates and Times in Excel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#DATES-AND-TIME-IN-EXCEL) section of the Excel::Writer::XLSX docs. In particular the first part: *There are two important things to understand about dates and times in Excel: 1. A date/time in Excel is a real number plus an Excel number format.
2. Excel::Writer::XLSX doesn't automatically convert date/time strings in write() to an Excel date/time.*

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string = "002212212"; # => 00:22:12.212

$string =~ s/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})/$1:$2:$3.$4/;

print $string, "\n\n";
```

Comment: While this provides an answer, you can improve it a lot by adding an explanation of what your code does and why it needs to do that. Links to documentation are also always appreciated. :)

Comment: In case they can't figure out that `\d` matches a digit? Nah, this is the quintessential example of self-documented code.

Comment: "Self-documented" and "regex" have never belonged in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is something custom to Excel. The single quote `'` is used to force numbers into a string context in Excel. It's not displayed, but it makes Excel put the number to the left instead of the right.

[image: number as a string goes to the left]

You can also see the little green triangle in the top left corner, and the `<!>` that it shows next to the selected column.

I believe that Excel::Writer::XLSX tries to guess if you have a string or a number, but because of your rather strange format `00:22:12.212` it doesn't see it right.

You can try using [`write_number`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_number(-$row,-$column,-$number,-$format-)) instead of `write`. But we would need to know what exactly you have in your variable `$month[$i][7]`. If it's the literal `00:22:12.212` this might not help.

Comment: @ra I think you're mixing things. The format in Excel is for displaying, not storing. Internally this is just a number. You need to give it a float. You don't need mysql to calculate. The alternative would be to use a simple text field in Excel and ignore the '.

Comment: I have tried write_number and got the follow warning:  `Argument "00:01:44.375000" isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Work‌​sheet.pm line 2190`  

I have used the follow query to get that variable: `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(avg(timediff(column1,column2))) FROM table;`  The both column is using `date(5)`  type in MySQL.

Comment: You now essentially have a different question @Rafael. If you want numbers, use numbers. The `00:01:04.375000` is a **string**. It contains colons `:`. Of course you cannot do additions on that because additions work on numbers only. You need to decide. Either you want to put numbers into Excel and tell Excel to format them like that string, or you want strings in that format. Does Excel mind that the `'` when you do calculations there?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to insert time values with excel writer in perl.

Step 1: write the data to another column.

```
$worksheet1->write("A2","00:22:12.212",$datablank);
```

- The format with text size=1 and color=white. That way the column A2 will look like empty. (don't write any more to A2 column).

  `my $datablank = $workbook->add_format(
  bold => 0,
  size => 1,
  border => 0,
  text_wrap => 1,
  color => 'white',
  num_format => '[h]:mm:ss.000'
  );`

Step 2: write a formula with `TIMEVALUE` as bellow:

```
$worksheet1->write_formula("A1","=TIMEVALUE(A2)",$datatimeformat);
```

- The format:

  `my $datatimeformat = $workbook->add_format(
  center_across => 1,
  bold => 0,
  size => 11,
  border => 1,
  text_wrap => 1,
  color => 'black',
  bg_color => '#ffffff',
  num_format => 'hh:mm:ss.000',
  align => 'center',
  valign => 'vcenter');`

Notice: We should used the values from A1 column to draw the chart.